# In the JavaScript SDK: How to properly update and capture a transaction in onApprove when excluding onShippingChange event?

Tags: paypal

In using the JavaScript SDK with `commit=false` the buyer is sent back to the client page after the payment information is approved through the `Continue` button rather than `Pay Now`.  If only the price of the products are included in the creation of the order, such that no shipping options are provided within the PayPal windows, how is this to be adjusted in the `onApprove` event handler of `paypal.Buttons()`?

According to the `actions` object returned in the `onApprove` event handler, there are four actions `authorize, capture, get, patch`.  Are we to `get` the order data, calculate values based upon the shipping address to update shipping options and sales tax, and then, upon user click for approval, do we `patch`?  If so, do we still need to `capture`?

Also, is this a safe method?  For example, if a buyer were to have the purchase approved to pay from a PayPal balance, and then clicks `Continue` and changes the shipping method in the DOM such that the revised total exceeds that PayPal balance, what would take place upon `patch` or `capture`?

The reason I'm asking is that I want to bypass the `onShippingMethod` for the reasons described in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71543224/sales-tax-not-updated-when-shipping-option-is-changed-if-buyer-pays-with-credit).  I know how to perform the calculations, but I don't understand how to communicate that to PayPal properly.

Thank you.

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {

  actions.order.get().then( function(orderData) {
    /* Update values based upon orderData and DOM capture of shipping option and sales tax.*/
    btn_finalize.addEventListener( 'click', () => { return finalize(); }, false );
    /* Display finalize button */
  }); // close get()

  function finalize() {
     return actions.order.patch([{
       op: "replace",
       path: "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='prod_0001'/amount",
       value: {
         value: oTotal.toFixed(2),
         currency_code: "USD",
         breakdown: {
           item_total: {
             currency_code: "USD",
             value: order.discSub.toFixed(2)
            },
            shipping: {
              currency_code: "USD",
              value: shippingAmount.toFixed(2)
            },
            tax_total: {
              currency_code: "USD",
              value: tax_total.toFixed(2)
            }
         }
       }
     }
   ]); // close patch
  } // close finalize()
 } //close onApprove
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are we to get the order data, calculate values based upon the shipping address to update shipping options and sales tax, and then, upon user click for approval, do we patch? If so, do we still need to capture?

Patch as soon as you know what final total will be (no need to wait for user confirmation to patch, unless that confirmation has inputs that will change the total).  After user has given final confirmation with a "Pay Now" or "Complete Order" - style action you display, and the order has been patched, then do the capture.

> changes the shipping method in the DOM such that the revised total exceeds that PayPal balance, what would take place upon patch or capture?

If the payer doesn't have enough money available from the funding source (bank, balance, card, etc) to complete a transaction, the capture will fail with an error. This result will be the same as any other situation in which a capture can fail.